# Can I add the 2nd monitor with Apple Cinema display

Tags: cinema-display

I have a MBP 2017 13" connected to a cinema display. Right now I'm looking for a 4K 60hz display with USBC for charging my MBP. In that case, can both monitors work? I connect to the Cinema Display with an adapter.

Comment: You may find that your Intel graphics has to work very hard all the time, which may ramp the fans up all the time, to deal with the heat produced.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this usually does work. Connecting another monitor with PD (Power-delivery) should not change the behaviour on your other ports. Your [MacBook's](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP754?locale=de_DE) specs specifically mention the ability to support two 4K monitors @60Hz, so one with a lower resolution will be no problem. I myself have been using a 4K PD (USB-C) LG monitor and a 2K monitor connected through a hub on a 2017 15" MBP.

However, your graphics card needs to push many more pixels, i.e. other graphics related tasks may slow down depening on your usecase.

---

Just to clarify:

> Connecting another monitor [..] should not change the behaviour on your other ports

Of course your MacBook is limited at some point, i.e. connecting daisychained TB (Thunderbolt) devices and using an integrated USB hub in a monitor (many monitors using USB-C have this) will at some point lead to lower performance on these devices. However, you should only see decreasing speeds e.g. for external drives connected like that but the video output should generally be prioritized, i.e. not limited due to more connected other devices.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. It's rly helpful. btw, which 4k monitor are u using? the LG ultrafine?

Comment: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07MKT1W65/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1 its this one